# How to check if a variable is between two values?

Tags: java

I am having trouble finding a way to compare a data value between two conditions - in this case greater and less than.

#### Example:

```
int variable = 2500;

3000 < variable > 1000
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try using an if statement for this

```java
if(variable>1000 && variable<3000){
  //do something here 
}
```

Hope this will help you.